# Find all $a, b, c$ such that $|ax+by+cz| +$ $|bx+cy+az| +$ $|cx+ay+bz| =$ $|x| + |y| + |z|$ holds for all $x,y,z$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, absolute-value

Find all triplets of real numbers $a, b, c$ such that $$|ax+by+cz|+|bx+cy+az|+|cx+ay+bz|=|x|+|y|+|z|$$
is true for all real number $x,y,z$.

I tried a lot but couldn't solve the problem.
$x=y=z=1 \implies |a+b+c|=1 $
and  $x=y=0,z=1\implies  |a|+|b|+|c|=1$

But I have no idea how to use this to find all possible values of $a, b $ and $c$. How can I proceed further?

Comment: Your title seems to mean you want *one* solution (a,b,c). If so, there are obvious answers. If you want *all* solutions, say it explicitely.

Comment: + include your  question in the body, not only (and not necessarily) in the title.

Comment: Hint, there are six triplets. One of them is $1,0,0$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack It's not obvious to me that your edit is what the OP meant vs. for example *find all $a,b,c$ given an arbitrary triplet $x,y,z$*, in which case the answer would be very different.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Having examined the editing, I agree with dxiv.  The original editing started: For all $~x,y,z,~ \cdots .~$ This suggests that $~a,b,c~$ is supposed to be derived as a function of the three **unknown constants** $~x,y,z.~$

Comment: **To the original poster:** There may have been a mistake in interpretation, when your posting was edited.  Please see my last comment.  Then, please review the posting as it currently is written.  If the posting as it is currently written does not represent the question that you are trying to pose, please re-edit your posting, to restore the posting to the question that you are trying to ask.  If you have difficulty doing this, and need help restoring the original posting, please leave a comment addressed to @user2661923.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry that I did not leave a comment after I had edited the post. Yes, I knew I might have changed the meaning of the question **very significantly**.  I thought about it. I checked [this thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1951553p13472153) and [this thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2175781p16232130). I believe my change should be good.

Comment: @Amin Of course, please revert (and improve) if my version is not what you meant.  Please add some context such as where you encountered this problem or why you created this problem.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I think there should be 8 pairs

Comment: @Apass.Jack I think your edit was very helpful. Can you break your answer down for me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $x=y=z=1 \implies |a+b+c|=1 $
> and  $x=y=0,z=1\implies  |a|+|b|+|c|=1$

You have made great progress as quoted above.

---

Towards a contradiction, suppose at least two of $a,b,c$ are nonzero. WLOG, suppose both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. If $x=a$, $y=-b$, $z=0$, then
$\quad |ax+by+cz| = |a^2-b^2| < a^2 + b^2$
$\quad |bx+cy+az| = |ba-cb| \le |b||a| + |c||b|$
$\quad |cx+ay+bz| = |ca-ab| \le |c||a| + |a||b|$
Adding the inequalities, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad |ax+by+cz|+|bx+cy+az|+|cx+ay+bz|\\
&< (|a|+|b|)(|a|+|b|+|c|)\\
&= |a| + |b| \\
&= |x|+|y|+|z|,\\
\end{aligned}$$
which contradicts with the given condition. Hence, at most one of $a,b,c$ is nonzero.

Since $|a|+|b|+|c|=1$, we know $(a,b,c)$ must be one of the following six triplets.
$(\pm1, 0, 0), (0, \pm1, 0), (0, 0, \pm1).$

It is straightforward to verify each of the six triplets satisfies the given condition.

---

**Exercise 1.** Find all pairs of real numbers $a, b$ such that $|ax+by|+|bx+ay|=|x|+|y|$ for all real number $x$ and $y$.

**Exercise 2.** Find all quadruplets of real numbers $a, b, c,d$ such that $|aw+bx+cy+dz|$ $+|bw+cx+dy+az|$ $+|cw + dx+ay+bz|$ $+|dw +ax+by+cz|$ $=|w|+|x|+|y|+|z|$ is true for all real number $w,x,y,z$